# Rails - pretty URI instead of Restful URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, rest, uri

in View

```
<tr onclick="window.location.href = '<%= url_for :controller => "products", :action => "index", :product => release.product_name, :version => release.version %>'" >
```

In controller

```
release  = Release.find_ver_rel(params[:product], params[:version])
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :template => 'releases/overview' }
end
```

It produces URI: `/products?product=Atlas&version=0.2`

How to get "pretty uri" like  `/products/product/Atlas/version/0.2`?

Comment: The URI produced there isn't a RESTful URI; your "pretty URI" is closer to what Rails would generate for you using the resources helper.

Answer (score 0):

In your routes file `config/routes.rb` put

`match '/products/product/:name/version/:version' => 'product#index', :as => :something`

This way, you can either pass variables directly into `something_path(:name => 'Name')`, or fetch it from `params[:name]`.